# Catching array index error

Tags: arrays, go, error-handling

I'm just starting to learn Go, and I implemented an algorithm that checks four consecutive array indexes for an equal value in both diagonal directions, vertical, and horizontal. I designed it so that there is a function for each direction, and I'm wondering if there is a way for me to catch index errors without having to do the overhead to check if each index is in the range of index constraints.

```
func (state *State) checkTopLeftDiagonal(row, col int) bool {
    token := state.Board[row][col]
    b := token == state.Board[row-3][col-3] && token == state.Board[row-2][col-2] 
                  && token == state.Board[row-1][col-1]
    return b
}

func (state *State) CheckWinner(row, col int) bool {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        if state.checkTopLeftDiagonal(row+i, col+i) == true {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can catch a first index error using`defer`, but it would be impossible to recover the expression being calculated. Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: IMO make a method that returns the value at [row][col], put the bounds checks in there and return an error or a bool if its not in range. The overhead of this is negligible.

Comment: Bounds checking is the correct thing to do. Recovering panics incurs more overhead than a simple bounds check.

Comment: @Adrian Recovering a panic incurs more overhead **only during errors** while they incur less overhead on successfull lookups as you don't need to check anything. They still should be negligible unless we are talking about huge arrays.

Comment: @Adirio I seriously doubt it. Recovering a panic involves a `defer`, a `recover` and a comparison between two error (or even type assertion), which is more overhead to me than a boundary check.

Comment: Registering there recover handler incurs overhead whether or not it's triggered. This is also a case of favoring a horrible practice (panic as flow control) in order to get a dubious performance benefit that is unlikely to make any meaningful difference in application performance.

Comment: @leafbebop You guys are right, in this case it is a bigger overhead plus a bad practice (panic as flow control) but in some cases it may be slightly outperforming. I could provide examples but I don't think they will offer anything new to the OP. Just take into account that the order of execution is: check -> rest of the function vs defer -> rest of the function -> additional overhead so if the rest of the function is on a hurry and the check takes some time even if the total overhead is bigger the rest of the function may be executed before in the panic case.

Comment: @Adirio I can hardly imagine a situation that you cannot use a `else` to do the "overhead part" but `recover` can excluding normal panic handling. Would you please enlighten me?

Comment: @leafbebop Imagine you have to do some promised based execution, where you are actually returning the promise. For example for some sort of communication or BD read/write. You would want to prepare the promise as fast as you can as the bottle neck will be its execution but then you can affor d to do other things while it is getting served.

Answer (score 2):

*What overhead?*

"Heavy" and "slow" programs generally work with tens or hundreds of thousands of data points every second. A single if statement quite literally takes a handful of clock cycles out of the billions of clock cycles that your computer goes through every second (1 GHz = 1 billion clock cycles on a single core machine).

If you're worried about *bounds checking* overhead for (what seems to be) a fairly straightforward program, you shouldn't use Go. You shouldn't even use C++ or C. You should be writing this program directly in assembly and should spend hours fine-tuning each instruction to optimize on the scale of *fractions* of a nanosecond.

Like @leafbebop stated in the comments, any other pattern will carry significantly more overhead.

---

More generally, unless you go into a situation knowing the need for exceptionally high performance and low latency (such as electronic stock trading systems, gaming, or 3D rendering), it's usually better to build first and optimize later after you have "profiled" your code to identify the heavy parts. And unless your function is called millions of times a second, the amount of compute power that it'll use is virtually zero. What makes code slow is iterating over very large data sets, being bottlenecked waiting for the network (if processing thousands of network requests), or using large amounts of memory (in the range of gigabytes).

An if statement does not make a program slow.

Buying faster hardware is almost always cheaper than buying faster software (with more development time). :)